# Exported UTIs and Document types in xcode 9.1 with iOS 11

Tags: xcode, ios11

After the last update, without any change in code, my app will no longer appear in the "open in" menu. Has something changed in managing file types? My file is now associated with google drive and other generic apps!
Thank you for any help...

My code:

```
<key>CFBundleDocumentTypes</key>
<array>
    <dict>
        <key>CFBundleTypeIconFiles</key>
        <array/>
        <key>CFBundleTypeName</key>
        <string>Pin The World 2 File</string>
        <key>CFBundleTypeRole</key>
        <string>Editor</string>
        <key>LSHandlerRank</key>
        <string>Owner</string>
        <key>LSItemContentTypes</key>
        <array>
            <string>com.valgy.PintheWorld2</string>
        </array>
    </dict>
</array>

<key>UTExportedTypeDeclarations</key>
    <array>
        <dict>
            <key>UTTypeConformsTo</key>
            <array>
                <string>public.data</string>
            </array>
            <key>UTTypeDescription</key>
            <string>Pin The World 2 File</string>
            <key>UTTypeIdentifier</key>
            <string>com.valgy.PintheWorld2</string>
            <key>UTTypeTagSpecification</key>
            <dict>
                <key>public.filename-extension</key>
                <string>p2w</string>
                <key>public.mime-type</key>
                <string>application/PintheWorld2</string>
            </dict>
        </dict>
    </array>
```